# How to rollback only one branch from development when multiple branches have been merged on it

Tags: git, github

## My workflow:

1. There is a `master` branch
2. There is a `dev` branch
3. New feature branches are created based off `master` as and when required. These feature branches are then merged with `dev` so we can test it on our development server. Feature branches never take pull of any other branch other than `master` so they are pure in that any of these can be individually merged with `master` at any time.
4. If there is any conflict while merging any feature branch to `dev`, this is resolved on `dev` branch itself by switching to `dev` and then taking pull of that feature branch and resolving conflicts manually while on `dev` branch. So, no feature branch ever takes pull from `dev` branch to keep them pure.
5. Feature branches are based off `master` because sometimes one or more of the multiple features may not be ready for that month's deployment while all others have been completed and approved. In such cases, we are supposed to roll back the `dev` branch last month's state and then merge in all the approved branches leaving off the incomplete branches.

## Problem/question:

For this month's deployment, one of the 10 features is not ready and we need to pull this out from development so that all others can be tested once on development server without this incomplete branch and then can be merged with `master`.

First option I can think of is as mentioned above i.e. to rollback `dev` branch to an older state (say commit `abcdef`) where none of these feature branches was merged in it. Then I need to merge in all the approved branches only on `dev`. I can roll back to that old state using `git checkout abcdef`. But I think it goes to some hanging state after that. How will I be able to merge other branches in it like I would normally do on `dev` branch?

I also read somewhere about `git revert` command. Is it possible to resolve my issue using `git revert`?

Please note that the branch I need to pull out has to be merged in with `dev` again after this month's deployment.

Comment: `git revert` is the only "clean" way to rollback code. If you don't want to use this, you must rewrite your branch history. Rewrite history is a good practice if you want to update a feature branch (i.e rebase), but not if you want to rollback a merge or a list of commits.

Comment: okay thanks @sboye I am trying to use `git revert` to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you specify the parent branch (i.e. the "clean" one), you can do this with `git revert`. Something like this:

```
git revert -m 1 <merge SHA>
```

What this will do is create a new commit that reverts the changes in the merge. If you then later want to undo this (for instance, if you want to re-merge the problem branch), just revert the reverted commit.

Comment: Thanks but the commits I have to revert are not the latest ones. I have made several commits from other feature branches after this branch that has to be reverted.

Comment: `git revert`, in effect, generates a reverse diff of a given commit (or, in a merge commit, the merged changes). If you have to revert changes done after the merge, you have to do them in turn.